# Bypass Ldap to create a test User in Symfony project

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ldap

I'm currently using an ldap authentification (ldap tools) for my users in my Symfony project.
Everything is working absolutely fine.
The only problem is that I want to create a testAccount for some User outside my ldap network, and I don't have access to it. I can only manage my database, and since it requires the ldap auth, I can't create a regular user with FOSuserBundle.

```
ldap_tools:
domains:
    heve:
        domain_name: test.heve
        username: 
        password: 
        base_dn: "dc=test,dc=heve"
        servers: ['slnt-gtr04.test.heve']
security:
    # Set to null for no role to be assigned by default. Or set it to another role altogether.
    default_role: ROLE_USER
    # Set this to true if you want user attributes re-queried on each request.
    refresh_user_attributes: false
    # Set this to true if you want user roles re-queried on each request.
    refresh_user_roles: false
    guard:
        # This is the entry point/start path route name for the RedirectResponse of the Guard component
        default_target_path: '/'
        always_use_target_path: false
        target_path_parameter: '_target_path'
        use_referrer: true
        failure_path: null
        failure_forward: false
        failure_path_parameter: '_failure_path'
        remember_me: false
```

Is there any method to add an additionnal user to my ldap configuration (config.yml) or in the Apache service or something?

Thank you very much for your help. 
Younes

Comment: If it is not only ldap, use a second user provider [How to Use multiple User Providers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_user_providers.html)

Comment: thanks for your help. Indeed I've missed that point. Thank you very much  goto !

Comment: Actually I created another provider (with chain etc). worked well as auth but my whole security checks are based on the Ldap manager protocol (as for tokens, security roles etc) so I was not able to complete the testUser method... maybe in apache I can mock it I dunno